# When to weak and when to strong reference for nested block in block

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

I am looking for retain cycles in my block in my code. I have the following code in my `UITableViewController`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //[...] Not important code.
    __weak ELParkingLocationTVC *weakself = self; // Required? (1)
    cell.completionBlock = ^ {
        __strong ELParkingLocationTVC *strongSelf = weakself; // Required? (2)
        __weak ELParkingLocationTVC *weak2self = weakself; // Required? (3)
        [strongSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            __strong ELParkingLocationTVC *strong2self = weak2self; //Required? (4)
            ELMenuHistoryTVC *menuTVC = [strong2self.navigationController.viewControllers firstObject];
            [menuTVC.parentTabBarController moveToTab:ELMapViewControllerIndex completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                ElMainMapViewController *mainMapViewController = menuTVC.parentTabBarController.viewControllers[ELMapViewControllerIndex];
                //ELCustomParkplace *customParkplace = [strong2self parkplaceAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //(5)
                [mainMapViewController moveToCoordinate:customParkplace.coordinate];
            }];
        }];
    };
}
```

And have the following questions:

1. Which `__weak` and which `__strong` reference do I need? I am sure that 1st and 2nd I have to use, but I am really not sure about 3rd and 4th.
2. Can I use `@strongify` and `@weakify` here?
3. I think I don't need line (5), but I am not sure.

Any suggestion, link or nice comment will be appreciated!

Comment: try this article http://dhoerl.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/i-finally-figured-out-weakself-and-strongself/

Comment: I already know how basics, but thanks for link (especially `__typeof__(self)` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need a weak reference for the cell completion handler, because you have a reference cycle: `self > UITableView > UITableViewCell > self`.

You do not need to use the `__strong` qualifier.  Variables are strong references by default.

You do not need a weak reference for the animation and transition completion handlers, as those blocks are released as soon as the transition completes, but in this case they can't use `self` because they're nested inside of a block that can't capture `self`.

So keep `weakSelf` and `strongSelf`, and use the same `strongSelf` variable inside all of the nested blocks.